# If css module name equals react component name then css module not work

Tags: javascript, css-loader

**File structure:**

```
src/
--- DatePicker/
--- --- index.js
--- --- style.module.scss
```

style.module.scss

```
.DatePicker {
  background: black;

  input {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import CSS from "./style.module.scss";

export const DatePicker =(...props) => {
    return (
        <div className={CSS.DatePicker }>
                <input ref={inputRef}
                       type="text"
                       value={formattedDate}/>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Build without errors.
Class name not added to DOM.

If rename css module to "asdasd" everything work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename "DatePicker" to "datePicker".
CSS Modules not support Capitalize.